# Under what conditions are expected value and integral commutable?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, expectation

I am currently looking through some proofs in functional data analysis. Statements closely related to the following are used quite regularly in many of those proofs:

$$
E \left[ \int x(t) d t  \right]  = \int E \left[ x(t) \right]  d t 
$$

where $x$ is some random function in $L^2[0,1]$, usually with $E[x] = 0$ and $E[x^4] < \infty$.

Is this an equality that holds generally? If not, under what conditions does it hold? It would be great if you could give me a brief proof or a reference to further reading on this topic, as I can't really find anything so far.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fubini's theorem

Comment: Is this because $E \left[ \int x(t) dt \right] = \int \left( \int x(t) dt \right) d F_x$ and since $ x $ is assumed to be an integrable function?